# how to handle unwanted exiting of a command and its output in bash script

Tags: bash, scripts, window, xprop

I made a one liner script to auto hide a specific window when mouse is not hover over that window. It gets mouse position and geometry of the window and its position (topleftx,toplefty), I added its geometry to the window's starting position to get (bottomrightx, bottomrighty) coordinates, then it compares if mouse is over the window. If mouse is not on the window, it hides the window.

It works but only once, because `xprop` window info command that I use to extract window info in the script fails if it doesn't find the
window name in the window stack. It outputs an error message and `--help` message then exits.

I need `xprop` because it's the only window info command that gives info about `decoration id` of any window. Because mainstream window info tools in Linux only prints geometry and position of a window without its decoration. I wanted to include the window decoration for completeness.

How can I trick it into  working?

```
  while [ 1 ]
  do 
         string=$(xdotool getmouselocation 2>/dev/null | sed 's/x:\([0-9]\+\)[ \t]y:\([0-9]\+\)[ \t].*/\1;\2/' | tr ';' ',') 
         string2=$(xdotool getwindowgeometry $(xprop -name "kenn" | grep _COMPIZ_WINDOW_DECOR_INPUT_FRAME |  grep -Po ' # \K.*') | grep -Po ': \K.*' |cut -d" " -f1 | tr '\n' ',' | tr 'x' ','| sed 's/-[0-9][0-9]*/0/') 
         A="$string2$string" 
         IFS=, 
         set $A 
  if [[(($5 -lt $(($1+$3))))  && (($5 -gt $1))]] && [[(($6 -lt $(($2+$4))))  && (( $6 -gt $2 ))]]
         then echo "mouse is on the window"
  else 
         then echo "mouse is out of the window"
  fi 
  done
```

Comment: You should expand your one-liner into a multi-line script, at least here. It's very hard to read that way using a scroll bar for such a long line. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
(xprop -name "kenn" 2>/dev/null || echo "") |...
```

The stderr redirect gets rid of the error and the part after `||` kicks in if xprop bombs out.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I tried it but I still can not make it work

Comment: Your proposition fixed error related to `xprop` but I get another strange error message `bash: 1025+: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+")`